# opening json file to create chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am trying to create a graph from data I have in a json file. I am new to coding and am unsure of what I have done wrong here. The data does not show up in the console logs and i get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined at graph:71

This is my old javascript code

```
<script>
       var data;
       
       function preload(){
           data = loadJSON("/home/ubuntu/project/jason/data.json");
       }
       console.log(data);
</script>
<canvas id="chart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: data.date,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: data.mass,
```

The data in my json file looks like this

```
[{"date": "2020/07/28", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/29", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/30", "mass": 69.5}, {"date": "2020/07/31", "mass": 69.8},....]
```

I have edited my code I realised I hadn't edited it from a bar chart format with labels and coordinates. I want the date and the mass to be the x and y coordinates. I have also tried to implement the mapping you were talking about, but I'm not sure if I have done this correctly.

```
<script>
       var data;
       
       function preload(){
           data = loadJSON("/home/ubuntu/project/jason/data.json");
           
       }
      
       const labels = data.map((x) => x.date);
       const ycoordinate = data.map((x) => x.mass);
       console.log(data);
    </script>

<canvas id="chart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets:[{
               data: ycoordinante
                
            }],
        },
        options: {}});
</script>
```

Comment: you probably need to transform your json string into a javascript object. use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: the error means that variable called date, on line 71, is undefined. now you need to figure out why date on line 71 is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in `labels: data.date,` if you try to check your json response you will see an array of items, so that you cant access date item else if you specify index of data like `labels: data[0].date`

Another issue
You are try to use Line chart from Chartjs, and I think you need to check how you can pass data like this url: [Chartjs - Line](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html)  (you are put data.mass direct too and its most be fetched)

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

for example:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [168,170,178,190,203,276,408,547,675,734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10,16,24,38,74,167,508,784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2,2,7,26,82,172,312,433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    }
  }
});
```

So that, the solution is fetch all item from json and passing it like doing map for data like `data.map((data) => data.mass)` for datasets and the same for labels.

### Update 1

```js
let data = [{"date": "2020/07/28", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/29", "mass": 68.3}, {"date": "2020/07/30", "mass": 69.5}, {"date": "2020/07/31", "mass": 69.8}];

const labels = data.map((x) => x.date);
const ycoordinate = data.map((x) => x.mass);

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets:[{
           data: ycoordinate

        }],
    },
    options: {}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to acces an object field but you try to do it from an array this doesnt work that way. to achieve what you want you have to transform your array. You can do this with a map like this:

```
constlabels = data.map((x) => x.date)
const dataFormatted = data.map((x) => x.mass)
```

If you put those in your chart it will work

Comment: I have edited my code as above but it still doesn't work have I implemented your suggestion correctly?